# Meteorjs Accounts login invalid redirect url

Tags: amazon-ec2, meteor, haproxy

I have set up a meteorjs application in Amazon EC2 and its bind to subdomain like(dev.xyz.com).

I have added HAProxy to it with this settings of HAProxy:

```
frontend www-http
        bind 0.0.0.0:80
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
        default_backend www-backend

frontend www-https
        bind  0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /home/ubuntu/haproxycert/host.pem
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
        default_backend www-backend

backend www-backend
       redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
       #server www-1 171.30.0.185:80 check
        server www-1 127.0.0.1:3000 check
```

I have added loginButtons in the template but when I click the login with the services its taking the redirect url as http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/_oauth/google?close , instead of 
 http://dev.xyz.com/_oauth/google?close.

xx.xxx.xxx.xx is the ip of the ec2 instance.

I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me what I have missed or what is wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Before this happens, are you originally connecting to the site via the ip address (in the browser) or via the hostname?  Either way, his does not look like an haproxy configuration problem.

Comment: I am connecting with the hostname. Yes its more related to meteorjs accounts package than haproxy but as I am new to both I gave the config so it may help understand the question